# Using pytest to check the input prompt

Tags: python, pytest

Imagine I have a `Python` function that goes something like this:

```
def myFunction(argument: str) -> None:
  doStuff()
  result = input(f'{complicated_logic_involving_argument}: ')
  doOtherStuff()
```

I want to test the results of `myFunction()`, but I **also** want to test that the *complicated prompt* displays correctly for each possible `argument`.

The problem is when I try

```
@mark.parametrize(('argument', 'prompt'), (
  ('firstValue', 'Expected Prompt'),
))
def test_myFunction(argument: str, prompt: str, monkeypatch, capsys) -> None:
  monkeypatch.setattr('builtins.input', lambda _: 'whatever')
  myFunction(argument)
  # THIS IS WHERE MY TEST CODE FAILS!
  snapshot = capsys.readouterr()
  assert prompt in snapshot.out
```

The actual prompt doesn't seem to go to either `snapshot.out`, or `snapshot.err`. I have also tried using `capfd`, but no bliss.

Any on out o capture the prompt of input()`?

Comment: Instead of doing complicated logic inside of an f-string, why not handle it in a function that returns the f-string, and then you can do a separate set of test cases for just that prompt generation function?

Comment: Well, because then I would have to change the code :( The original code was written with the input(f'(....)') logic.

Comment: Are you prevented from changing the code?  If not, then this is exactly the correct solution.  Give each function a single responsibility.  The real purpose of `myFunction` is to `doStuff` and `doOtherStuff`.  The complex prompt logic should be handled by its own function, and then testing it is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Try separating the logic for the generation of the prompt into its own function.

```
def myFunction(argument: str) -> None:
  doStuff()
  result = input(generate_prompt_function(argument))
  doOtherStuff()

def generate_prompt_function(argument: str) -> str:
   # Do logic to generate prompt based on the different inputs
   return prompt_string
```

Now you can just test the return value of the `generate_prompt_function` without having to capture stdout.

```
@mark.parametrize(('argument', 'prompt'), (
  ('firstValue', 'Expected Prompt'),
))
def test_generate_prompt_function(argument: str, prompt: str) -> None:
    assert generate_prompt_function(argument) == prompt

@mark.parametrize(('argument', 'prompt'), (
  ('firstValue', 'Expected Prompt'),
))
def test_myFunction(argument: str) -> None
   # Now this can actually test myFunction if it is even necessary.
```

Comment: I understand the approach, but that would mean I would have to change the code! The `f'{...}'` expressions are along the lines of this: f'{myTime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') or 'No date available'}'

That's the effective way of writing them in the code. I just want to test tall the cases in all the logic.

Comment: It might help if you updated your question to show the actual logic you are trying to test instead of abstracting it.  Is the value of `myTime` one of the `argument` passed in to myFunction, or is it an output from `doStuff()` based on the values of `argument`?   The key point is that you aren't really trying to test input() or what it displays to screen, you're trying to test the logic for the generation of a string, and that logic should probably be handled by its own function. Yes it will require a refactor, but that refactor will be faster than trying to tweak pytest to read stdout.

Comment: As for the example expression `f'{myTime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') or 'No date available'}` you have given, there's really nothing to test there.  You don't need to test `datetime.strftime()`, as that's a built in function., so testing variations of year, month and day is not worthwhile, and there's no scenario where `myTime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` won't return a string.  The only odd cases are if myTime is a `time` object and not a `date` or `datetime`, in which case you will get the default of `'1900-01-01'`, and if its not a type with a strftime method, you'll get an AttributeError